# Custom implementation for MessageConverter for Spring boot REST application not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have an rest application build using Spring boot. The api request object is a custom object containing String and ASN1OctetString. So i have written a custom implementation for message converter.

But  iam unable to convert the inputStream to customVO object containing String andASN1OctetString.
**How can i convert the input stream to customVo object?**

I tried using the `ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);`, but it is giving an error like header not valid. 
Please let me know how i can solve this issue.

The deatils of code are given below.
The application has a controller as below :-

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/MyApp/postMessage", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8",consumes="ASN1OctetString/bytes;charset=UTF-8")
public DeferredResult<MyCustomVO> process(@Valid @RequestBody MyCustomVO myCustomVO, HttpServletRequest request){

    //service code
}
```

The Request bean is as follows:-

```
import com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString;

public class MyCustomVO {

    protected String actionDesc;
    protected ASN1OctetString transId;

    //setter getter methods
}
```

The custom implementation for message converter:-

```
public class MyCustomVOConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<MyCustomVO> {

public MyCustomVOConverter() {
    super();
}

public MyCustomVOConverter(org.springframework.http.MediaType supportedMediaType) {
    super(supportedMediaType);
}

public MyCustomVOConverter(MediaType... supportedMediaTypes) {
    super(supportedMediaTypes);
}

@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return MyCustomVO.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
protected MyCustomVO readInternal(Class<? extends MyCustomVO> clazz, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    MyCustomVO MyCustomVORequest= new MyCustomVO();

    InputStream is= httpInputMessage.getBody(); 
**//Need to convert the stream to customVO object**
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(MyCustomVO MyCustomVOResp, HttpOutputMessage httpOutputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a MediaType in your messageConverter otherwise the converter don't know for which media type he is responsible for. 
Do something like this to register a mediatype:

```
public MyCustomVOConverter() {
  MediaType type = new MediaType("ASN1OctetString", "bytes", Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(type)); 
}
```